# Can't reverse mouse scroll wheel on Ubuntu pc

Tags: mouse-wheel

The problem is simple enough, my scroll wheel scrolls things up when I'm scrolling down, and the opposite. I'd like to fix this, as I have no idea why anyone would ever want it this way. It's literally the opposite of how it should work...

I looked at the mouse settings, and there's Enable Natural Scrolling, which didn't seem to do anything, and a choice between right and left primary buttons.

I also looked in the `dconf-editor`, but found nothing to do with my issues, and tried to do the `gsku` thing with the number line, but evidently `gsku` doesn't exist anymore... not that I'd have known how to use it.

Comment: If you have another question, please use "Ask Question".

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate which DE you are using.  Some desktop environments offer more user customization than others...

If you are using KDE (Kubuntu), all you need to do is check "**Reverse scroll direction**".

You can find this system setting under the "**General**" tab in **System Settings > Input Devices > Mouse**

[image: System Settings screenshot of Mouse options]